Malformed Json Data from Spring Webflux
I am responsible for providing an API that must return a large number of data (around 500,000 to 7,000,000 rows) from a mysql database. To do this we opted for streaming with Spring Webflux. The implementation is correct, however when receiving the JSON data returned is malformed in certain places and in a completely random manner. I've been struggling with this problem for several days now.
As you can see in the source code, I first retrieve the total number of lines present in the database before doing internal paging and retrieving the data asynchronously via Threads, then these threads are reorganized and their data is concatenated to the output stream. I have the impression that this is the part that I didn't manage well because the data in the flow overlaps. Your help will be of great use to me.
Service class source code:
    @Override
    public Flux<ObjectReturn> getAllFromDifferentiel() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        logger.info("Appel de la methode getAllFromDifferentiel()");
        //Initialisation du flux de sortie
        returnedFlux = Flux.empty();

        //Recuperation du total de ligne
        Mono<Integer> totalRecords = repository.count();
        int total = totalRecords.toFuture().get();
        
        //Debut des calculs
        int relicat = total % limit;
        totalPage = (total / limit) + (relicat > 0 ? 1 : 0);

        logger.info("Total page possible: " + totalPage);
        Thread[] tasks = new Thread[totalPage];

        for (int indexPage = 0; indexPage < totalPage; indexPage++) {
          
            //Lancement en parallèle des requetes de pagination

            int finalIndexPage = indexPage;

            tasks[indexPage] = new Thread(() -> {

                offset = finalIndexPage == 0 ? 0 : limit * finalIndexPage + 1;
                logger.info("Page = " + (finalIndexPage + 1) + "      Offset =" + offset);

                //Regroupement des flux générés apres execution de la requete
                returnedFlux = Flux.concat(returnedFlux , repository.getAllByPage(limit, offset).map(ObjectReturn.INSTANCE::mapToDTO));

            });
            tasks[indexPage].start();

            //Agencement ordonné des tâches
            try {
                tasks[indexPage].join();

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        }

        return returnedFlux 
                .doOnError(error -> {
                    logger.error("--------- Stream error ------------" + error.getMessage(), error);
                    throw new IllegalStateException(error);
                })
                .doOnCancel(() -> {
                    logger.info("--------- Stream canceled -------------");
                })
                .doOnComplete(() -> {
                    logger.info("--------- Stream completed -------------");
                });

    }

Controller source code:
@GetMapping(value = "getData", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_NDJSON_VALUE)
public Flux<ObjectReturn> getAllFromDifferentiel() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    return service.getAllFromDifferentiel();
}

Result after API Call:
Response payload
As you can see in the json opened with VsCode, some data is malformed, therefore causing an irregularity in the final json file. And this problem occurs at several levels in the resulting file.

totalRecords.toFuture().get(); this is blocking, this is super not allowed, new Thread you should NEVER create your own thread in a webflux application so remove that. You are trying to code regular java in a webflux application. Stop that and look up a tutorial, what mono is, what flux is and how you code using them because it is very clear that you dont know the basics. Im sorry im harsh here but you need to know the basics. Your function body should start with return repository.count().flatMap( value -> { ...your code goes here... })

I know you're right I don't yet master all the details of webflux, if you have a link that could help me it will be useful, I did with the tutorials and courses that I could find on the web. I will take your recommendation into account by starting as you said and see what happens. And also could you give me a code example of how I should implement the asynchronous call of paginated queries that I made using thread please? Thanks in advance

No i dont have a code example or any links, use the official reactor docs. Its very rude to ask for help when it is shown that extremly little has been made to understand the absolut basics. Good luck
